# Select rows with same other ID in join table

Tags: sql

I'm struggling with writing this basic SQL query.

I have two tables. `person` and `address_join`.

```
create table person (id bigint);
create table person_address (person_id bigint, address_id bigint);
```

Given one person's ID I want to find other people they share an address with. It's also worth noting that a person can have more than one address.

How can I make this query return other `person` records that share the same `address_id`?

```
select * from person
join person_address on person_address.person_id = person.id
where person.id = ?;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can answer this with a self join on `person_address`:

```
select pa2.*
from person_address pa1 join
     person_address pa2
     on pa1.address_id = pa2.address_id and
        pa1.person_id <> pas2.person_id
where pa1.person_id = ?
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from person p
join person_address a on a.person_id = p.id
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM person_address x
    WHERE x.person_id = ?
    AND x.address_id = a.address_id
    AND x.person_id <> p.person_id
    );
```